# Run a console application in a Mono Docker container

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mono

I have a console application that works without problems on Windows. 
Inside the `/bin/release` folder I have some build artifacts (.dll, .exe, and so on) plus a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mono:4.0

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["mono", "./EntryPoint.exe"]
```

I build the image, run the container but when EntryPoint.exe is hitted I get something like:

```
Rebus.Workers.ThreadBased.ThreadWorker DEBUG (Rebus 1 worker 1): Starting (thread-based) worker Rebus 1 worker 1
Default Error: 0 : An exception occurred creating the host System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
 instance of an object
  at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.get_ParentDefinitionMethodInfo () [0x00000] in <filename un
known>:0
  at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.GetParentDefinition (System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, B
indingFlags flags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.GetParentDefinition (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propert
y) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.IsDefined (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo element, System.T
ype attributeType, Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.HasAttribute (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member, System.T
ype type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Ninject.Selection.Heuristics.StandardInjectionHeuristic.ShouldInject (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member) [0x00000
] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Ninject.Selection.Selector+<>c__DisplayClass3.<SelectPropertiesForInjection>b__2 (IInjectionHeuristic h) [0x00000]
in <filename unknown>:0
```

I installed Portability Analyzer extension to Visual Studio and it looks like some problems on Mono 3.3. Frequently problems are:

- `add_SerializeObjectState(...)`
- `System.Security.SecurityTransparentAttribute #ctor`
- `System.Configuration.ElementInformation.get_IsPresent()`
- `System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_MemberType()`
- `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.BeginConnect()`

The most affected library are:

- Common.Loggin 3.3.1
- EntityFreamework 6
- MongoDB 1.9.2
- Newtonsoft.Json 7
- Topshelf 3.3.1

As I've already said, .NET portability Analyzer check portability against Mono 3.3 (right now 4.2 is out). How can I check against a newer version (Mono 4 would be appreciated)? I hope that some errors would disappear on Mono 4.

What can I do? What if a third party library (for instance MongoDB) have portability problems that stops me?

Comment: From error it seems problem is with NInject? Tried to compile under mono? Can you replace NInject with another DI container?

Comment: It is not a recommended practice to have a statement like "COPY . /app" that copies everything from the current directory. Copying specific files from there is good or copying from a subdirectory of "." is okay. The reason is that the dockerfile is included in the COPY statement. Then any change to the text of the dockerfile will invalidate the cache from the COPY statement onward, causing performance problems. Furthermore, you cannot exclude the dockerfile using a .dockerignore file, because it must NOT be ignored - it must be read and processed.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bunch of things. The docker file for mono:4.0 on docker hub is from wheezy, and does a mono-devel rather than a mono-complete installation. It would be an idea to discount those factors (i.e. are you running on a debian derivative or an SE derivative? and, do you need a mono-complete install?) if not already done so. Additionally if you are compiling on Windows and simply copying and running on linux then you *may* run into compatibility issues, so building using your target mono would also help discount that. Also where and how are you baking your docker image?

Comment: I'm baking my app simply `docker build -t myimg .`

Comment: Ok, so that should not be a problem then. I'd try recomp'ing on mono next and discounting that.

Comment: Building with xbuild (i.e. using Mono tools) turns out a trasformation error on App.config. I've replaced SlowCheetah with SlowMonkey and it works like a charm! :)